# probability of failing

Tags: probability

The probability of a component to fail in each day is 0.0002
After 12.000 days of use the probability to not fail is more than the probability of failure.

Any hint on how to approach the question?

If the component has probability of failure of 0.0002 each day would it be the same after 12.000 days?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The probability to **not** fail during a specific hour is $1-0.0002=0.9998$. The probability of not having failed at all in $12000$ hours is thus $0.9998^{12000}=0.09...$ (assuming independence), while the probability of failing *at least once* during the same timeframe is $1$ minus that probability, which is much larger.

The claim as stated is therefore false under the assumption of statistical independence.

Comment: thanks, specifically we use the power because it implies that it did not fail before? (so the multiplication rule for AND)? right?

Comment: Whether or not it has failed before is irrelevant, as the probabilities for the individual hours are looked at separately (so the multiplication rule applies). Basically, you are computing the probability that for ALL hours, the "not" event has occurred.

Comment: thanks..saying that for ALL hours is the same as saying that it never happened, so AND... no? or I am just confusing myself maybe..

Comment: Yes, that's correct, we're ANDing the events together.